# Driver IC for 3-4v, 5A Tamiya motors

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, dc-motor

I have some tamiya motors and would like to use them on a project, the problem is when i looked up the data sheet of my motor (Tamiya plasma dash 4WD). the motors are at 3volts , 4-5amps. this is quite difficult since common drivers (L293d) only drives motor above 4.5 volts at 1A. I have read that MOSFETS are good, but i don't have a lot of experience using MOSFETS. But i think i can learn, question is there a MOSFET that can carry it though.

Does anyone know a common IC that does the Job?

If there is none, a workaround to drive the motors is also greatly appreciated.

PS. i will be an arduino Microcontroller , with either a LiPo or Eneloops batteries.

EDIT : I would like for it to be bi directional, Electronic Braking would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the ability to reverse the direction of rotation required? Is electronic braking required? It's perhaps the first thing to narrow down, as it determines what kind of topology is required (full blown H-bridge vs a single MOSFET and a flyback diode)

Comment: Yes i would like to reverse the direction( H- bridge), Electronic braking is also ideal, Do you have a specific IC or a circuit in mind?

Comment: You problem is 3V motors @5A use expensive $30 driver boards https://www.pololu.com/product/2503  , whereas 15V @ 1A uses cheap drivers

Comment: these are cheaper but beyond your scope https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-siliconix/SIC631CD-T1-GE3/SIC631CD-T1-GE3CT-ND/5806708

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but yes pololu is out of my reach in my country. ordering from them would take months to arrive.

Comment: maybe supplier of motor can offer drivers

Comment: Or get from any online store  or run these in tandem  https://www.pololu.com/product/2130  or send a friend some money to mail to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bidirectional control with braking you can use 4 MOSFETs wired in 'H-Bridge' configuration, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEln0s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M1 and M4 are turned on to run the motor one direction, and M2 and M3 are turned on for the other direction. For braking you turn on either both upper FETs or both lower FETs, which puts a short across the motor.

PWM can be applied (using digitalWrite or a custom PWM routine) to the lower N-channel FETs to control motor speed. The upper P-channel FETs are turned on by negative voltage, so you make the digital outputs LOW to turn them on and HIGH to turn them off.

Resistors R1-R4 ensure that all FETs are turned off when the Arduino starts up. They prevent the I/O pins from 'floating' before being initialized.

Note that you must **never** turn on both upper and lower FETs on one side at the same time, or current will 'shoot through' both FETs and short out the battery. When testing you should wire a current limiting device (eg. a light bulb) in series with the battery, until you are sure that the firmware is reliable.

Most H-bridge designs include level converter circuits to boost the Gate voltage on the upper FETs. You don't need this because the battery voltage is lower than the Arduino's logic voltage, so it can directly drive the FETs with sufficient voltage. However if you power the motor with a 2 cell NiMH battery then the upper FETs must be rated to turn on fully with 2.4V, or if you use a single cell Lipo 3.7V. The lower FETs get 5V on the Gate so they only have to be 'logic-level' types.

The FETs should be rated for much higher current than the motor, both to prevent overheating and to reduce voltage drop (at this low voltage even fractions of a volt may noticeably reduce motor power). Finding P-channel FETs with appropriate ratings may be difficult. Here's one example:- [NDP6020P P-Channel FET, -2.5V gate, -20V, 24A max](https://solarbotics.com/product/17174/). If you cannot obtain suitable P-channel FETs in your country then you could use all NMOS devices with level converters to drive the upper FETs. 'Logic-level' FETs would need at least 4.5V more than the battery voltage, ie. >7V.

The Dash Plasma is a high performance motor designed to produce maximum possible power at low voltage. Since the Arduino needs at least 5V, you might consider using a motor designed to draw lower current at higher voltage - then you might be able to use a single battery to power both.

Comment: Thank you , can you list me alternative FETS ? Just incase i could not find the one you mentioned ?